# Insertar un campo de tipo DATE en MySQL desde una consulta preparada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas. Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar una fecha en una tabla MySQL desde PHP con una consulta preparada. Tengo el siguiente bloque de código:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ARTICULOS (CODIGO, FECHA) VALUES (?, ?)";
$resultado = mysqli_prepare ($conexion, $query);
if ($resultado == false)
{
     echo "Error fatal";
     mysqli_close($conexion);
     exit();
}
$codigo = "5555";

// Cadena con la fecha
$cadena_fecha_mysql = "2015-08-24";
$objeto_DateTime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $cadena_fecha_mysql);

$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($resultado, "ss", $codigo, 
                              $objeto_DateTime);
if ($ok == true)
{
    echo "Estoy en 1<br>";
    $ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
    if ($ok == true)
    {
        echo "Estoy en 2<br>";
    }
    else 
    {
        $error = mysqli_errno($conexion);
        echo "Error $error en la instruccion $query<br>";
        echo "2 ha fallado<br>";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "1 ha fallado<br>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Se imprime:
Estoy en 1

Y salta uan excepción en la linea de mysqli_stmt_execute:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string

He probado ya muchas cosas y no me funciona nada. 
El campo de la tabla `ARTICULOS` es de tipo `DATE` (ni `DATETIME` ni `TIMESTAMP`)

Comment: Has probado pasándolo como `string` sin convertirlo a `date`

Comment: ¿Poniendo esto así no funciona `$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($resultado, "ss", $codigo, 
                              $cadena_fecha_mysql);`?

Comment: Hola Kenvin. Si, lo he probado y a la hora de ejecutarse la sentencia sql me da un error cuyo código indica que el formato del campo es incorrecto.

Comment: Hola Cedano, no funciona, hice las pruebas hace unos días y fallaba al ejecutar la sentencia preparada. Recogiendo el código de error SQL me di cuenta de que el formato de fecha no era el correcto (puers así le estaba pasando un stringm no un DATE)

Comment: No entiendo el motivo por el cual se bloquean aqui las respuestas de los usuarios. No creo haber molestado a nadie con ninguna de mis respuestas

Comment: @CarmenEncinas Stack Overflow no es un foro, las respuestas deben usarse para responder a la pregunta y no para añadir más información o pedir clarificación a los usuarios. Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que yo recuerde podrías mandar el String directo a la consulta, pero de preferencia ocupa comillas simples.

Por Otro lado el formato que acepta MySQL de fecha es YYYY-mm-dd, por lo tanto tu función debería ser:

```
date('YYYY-mm-dd', $cadena_fecha_mysql);
```

Comment: Hola. Mira si tu haces lo siguiente:

Answer (score 0):

Intenta primero convirtiendo el **String** en **Timestamp**:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($string);
```

Y luego en **Date**:

```
date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Otra forma sería utilizando un DATE_FORMAT:

```
DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04', '%W %M %Y')
```